# Group timestamp information by date and hour in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this timestamp metric which shows the following information:
2021-08-30 22:10:22.838 UTC

I would like to split and group this info by date and hour, so it should look something like this in BQ:

Date: 2021-08-30
Hour: 22:00:00 UTC

Anyone know how do do this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the date and hour you can use this (replacing `your_ts` with the appropriate field name).

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM your_ts) dt,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM your_ts) hr
FROM tbl
```

If you want to keep the formatting you provided (returning strings), you can try something like this.

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F", your_ts) dt,
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%X", TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(your_ts, HOUR))
FROM tbl
```